# Permutations vs. Combinations

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

What are the word modifiers in order to distinguish a given if it is a permutation or a combination? Or simply describe what is permutation and combination.

Answer (score 3):

"Permutation" vs. "Combination" is not about "choosing" or "not choosing". It's about whether the *order* matters or not.

If order does not matter, it is a **combinations** problem.  If order does matter, it is a **permutations** problem.

And there is also a difference between how you count and what you are counting.

[Here's one interesting link. You can see.](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://magoosh.com/gre/2016/gre-math-difference-between-combinations-and-permutations/&ved=0ahUKEwjh6tWWrZ7RAhURTI8KHZJuBbcQFgg4MAI&usg=AFQjCNFcKbV11isgkmU9adVb64VuVR1Lug)

Answer (score 2):

The only difference between them is that in a permutation the order of the elements matters while in a combination doesn't.

Comment: I think you got that reversed.

Comment: I've just edited. Thank you very much, my mind usually reverses concepts.

Comment: No worries. You can always reverse them back.